# How do I make a class in c# so I can click a button on 1 form to update data on a second form?

Tags: c#, winforms, class, button

I am currently making an rpg using Winforms for a school project. However my knowledge on classes is so limited that I'm having trouble making a proper class that takes in data from 1 form, is used in the second form, then sent back to the first form.

The process I'm trying to accomplish is like this:

- main form opens a second form that displays items in a listbox.
  [1](https://imgur.com/a/EQHA4fO)
- when you select an item and press a button to use it, the items effects are applied. 
  [2](https://imgur.com/a/W0cp3rX)
- The data for the effect is in the first form where many other calculations are made with the same data.
  [3](https://imgur.com/a/92XuWKE)

I keep running into the problem of making a new object of a class and the data from the first form is reset. How would I go about either using an existing object from the first form, or creating a reference class maybe?

This is the function I want to run on the first form when the button on the second form is clicked.

```
public void SmallPot()
        {

            currentPHP += pHP * .25;

            if (newPHP > pHP)
            {

                newPHP = pHP;

            }

            pHPBarUpdate = (int)(newPHP / pHP * 377);

            pnlCurrentPHP.Width = pHPBarUpdate;

            newPHP = currentPHP;

        }
```

Expected: 
When I click the use button on the popup form it closes and the items effects are displayed on the Main form.

What Happens:
Since I create a new object of form one in form two, all my variables are reset to 0 before the calculation, resulting in nothing happening after the second form closes.

Comment: The correct way to handle this scenario is through _events_ Your second form define an event, your first form subscribes to this event, your second form raises the event, your first form receives the notification and all the data required in the event handler given at the subscription time.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!! Do you happen to have a link on how to do this or an example of how this would look in a situation similar to mine? We havn't worked with events yet in our Program and any kind of reference to how to do this would be helpful! Also if this ends up fixing my problem, post it as an answer instead of a comment so I can pick it as the proper answer to my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you a general guideline to implement a solution based on event definition and raising

Let's start from your second form where you need to communicate to the first form the event

```
public class Form2 : Form
{
    // start creating the delegate type
    public delegate void OnItemSelected(string itemName);

    // declare the public event that this form will raise
    public event OnItemSelected ItemSelected;


    protected void cmdItemUse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         // When the user clicks to select an item....
         string itemName = GetItemSelectedFromList();

         // Check if someone is interested in this item selection
         if(ItemSelected != null)
             ItemSelected.Invoke(itemName);
    }
}
```

Now we change something in the first Form. We need to create the second form and before displaying it we subscribe to the event exposed by the second form

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
     ... other stuff....

     protected void cmdOpenSelection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         using(Form2 frm = new Form2())
         {
             // Subscribe the event giving it a method inside this class
             // that doesn't return anything and receives a string
             // as required by the delegate type of the event
             frm.ItemSelected += handleItemSelection;
             frm.ShowDialog(); // frm.Show();
         }
     }
     private void handlerItemSelection(string itemName)
     {
         // This method is a custom Event handler and inside Form1 
         // will be called by Form2 through the Invoke on the event variable 
     }
}
```

In the example above I choose to pass a simple string, but of course you could pass anything including a reference type like an instance of a class containing all the info
required by the Item selection.

Comment: On the first form where you have "frm.ItemSlected += handleItemSelection", what is this representing? Is there something specific I should be putting here or is it a general term or phrase?

Comment: This is the syntax used when you want to assign a method (handleItemSelection) to the Event in the second form instance. In this way the second form has all that is required to call back the code in the first form instance.